# Ubercart particular item has extra shipping fee domestic vs international

Tags: 6, ubercart

I am using Ubercart 2.9 with Drupal 6.

Is there a way to add an extra fee to a certain product that has one value for domestic and a different value for international?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the modules [Ubercart Fee](http://drupal.org/project/uc_fee) and [UC Catalog Conditional Actions](http://drupal.org/project/ca_catalog_terms)

On the fee admin page, admin/store/fees, add fees with the required additional amounts. Add two conditions to each fee: that the product is in the cart, and that shipping address is [your country] or [your country] and condition negated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [UC Multiprice](http://drupal.org/project/uc_multiprice)

> This module allows you to set a different product pricing for each
>   enabled country in Ubercart. It also got support for roles, currencies
>   and i18n

*Its only in dev version use at your own risk.*